# Spring Security ROLE_ANONYMOUS does not work when deny-by-default is activated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I had enabled deny-by-default feature of security. With this I want to provide anonymous access on some controllers. For that I had enabled Anonymous authentication.

If I use `antmacher.permitAll()` works fine. 
But if I am using `@PreAuthorize(value="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')")` with controllers does not work for me.

```
{
  "timeStamp": 1488692168652,
  "success": false,
  "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "class": "org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException"
}
```

Spring security Configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable();

        // enable anonymous access
        httpSecurity.anonymous();

        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
        //.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity.addFilterAt(jsonAuthenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // Call our errorHandler if authentication/authorization fails
        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new JwtAccessDeniedHandler());

        // don't create session
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilterBean(), RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl().disable();
    }
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize(value="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String execute() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `@PreAuthorize(value="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')")` and `anyRequest().authenticated()`, 
you have configured your security chain to authenticate all requests, this catches the anonymous request and rejects it, before it gets to the controller.

Either you can configure using `antMatchers("/").permitAll()` or `antMatchers("/").anonymous()` to pass through the security filter chain.

Comment: if we need to add antMatchers("/").permitAll() then whats the use of ROLE_ANONYMOUS?

Comment: @Deepak Agrawal: That's two different things, web security and method security. If you use both, you have to know that web security is checked first. Method security is only checked, if web security is passed.